# Erro com acentuação - Busca CEP - Magento

Tags: php, magento, codificação-de-caracteres, funções, acentuação

Olá, estou fazendo uma busca de endereço atraves do CEP em uma função, depois pego o resultado e crio uma sessão com o nome da cidade e o Estado, acontce que toda vez que tem uma cidade com acento, me retorna da seguinte maneira "S�o Paulo SP"

Segue a minha função para buscar o endereço atraves do CEP

```
    private function busca_cep($cep){  
    $resultado = @file_get_contents('http://republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep='.urlencode($cep).'&formato=query_string');  
    if(!$resultado){  
        $resultado = "&resultado=0&resultado_txt=erro+ao+buscar+cep";  
    }  
    parse_str($resultado, $retorno);   
    return $retorno;  
}
```

Depois em outra função, crio a sessão

```
    public function setCidadeEntregaAction(){
    $parametros = $_GET;
    $cep = $parametros['cep'];
    $resultado_busca = $this->busca_cep($cep); 
    //echo $cep . ' - ' . $resultado_busca['cidade'] . ' - ' . $resultado_busca['uf'];
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCidadedestino($resultado_busca['cidade'].' '.$resultado_busca['uf']);
}
```

E por ultimo, pra exibir a função no frontend, faço assim

```
   <?php $local = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getCidadedestino();
   echo $local;?>
```

Como exibir o Resultado com a acentuação correta, ou seja, "São Paulo SP"?

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, tente o seguinte

```
<?php echo utf8_decode($local);?>
```

Isso deve resolver se for erro de codificação.